# Manter div no ecrã

Tags: jquery, html, posicionamento, jquery-animate

Gostaria de saber como faço para que uma `div` animada (tenho função `JQuery keydown` que faz movimentar uma div) porém a `div` sai do ecrã e gostaria que apenas fosse até 20 px das margens.
Já exprimentei colocar essa div (div1) dentro de outra div (div2) e colocar `position:relative` e `overflow:hidden` na div2 mas mesmo assim a div1 saia da div2.
Também já exprimentei fazer algumas validações da posição da div1 mas infelizmente sem sucesso.

PS: Utilizar as setas do teclado para mover a div1.

Deixo abaixo o meu codigo:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    
    //var pos = $(".box").position();

    switch (e.which){
    case 37:    //left arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
             left: "-=50"
        });
        break;
    case 38:    //up arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            top: "-=50"
        });
        break;
    case 39:    //right arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            left: "+=50"
        });
        break;
    case 40:    //bottom arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            top: "+=50"
        });
        break;
    }
});
```

```css
.box{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 200px auto 0;
        background: yellowgreen;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Tem de analisar o `left` e `top` por código e não deixar animar se a próxima animação passar os limites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu fiz um ajuste no seu código para não deixar sair da tela pelo lado esquerdo.

Para as outras direções é só seguir a mesma lógica.

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    
    //var pos = $(".box").position();
    let pixels = 50;
    let margemMinima = 30;

    switch (e.which){
    case 37:    //left arrow key
        
        let novaPosicao = $(".box").offset().left - pixels;
        
        if(novaPosicao > margemMinima) {
          $(".box").finish().animate({
                left: "-=" + pixels
          });
        }
        break;
    case 38:    //up arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            top: "-=" + pixels
        });
        break;
    case 39:    //right arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            left: "+=" + pixels
        });
        break;
    case 40:    //bottom arrow key
        $(".box").finish().animate({
            top: "+=" + pixels
        });
        break;
    }
});
```

```css
.box{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 200px auto 0;
        background: yellowgreen;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Isso é uma boa ideia mas não dá para comparar a novaposicao com algum tamanho da página (por exemplo: comparar com margin-left ou assim) para que o limite seja sempre o mesmo, ou seja quando se vai para a esquerda logo o limite é X mas basta ir para a direita umas quantas vezes e voltar tudo para a esquerda que o limite passa a ser outro.